# How can I share a single live grafana dashboard by link?

Tags: share, influxdb, grafana

Is there a "Anyone with the link can view" feature in grafana?

I know there is a snapshot feature but it does not include live data, and there can be anonymous users with View permission, but I want to share several dashboards with different clients and do not want them to be able to see each other's dashboards. I also want links to just work for clients and not require authentication hassle. So, something similar to "Anyone with a link can view" from Google Docs or "Unlisted" on youtube.

If there is no such functionality, are there any alternatives? I do not mind moving to, e.g. chronograf.

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure if I understood your problem correct, haven't you tried Share dashboard option (there's a radio button for the same right next to star on the top your dashboard)?

Comment: I did try that. Does not seem to offer option to share __live anonymous__ link for __a single__ dashboard. Am I missing something?